# python code has a name error in a while loop

Tags: python

this is all of my code so far. the function works if I input x manually. I'm also just starting out so any general info on how to generally make it more pythonic would be apreciated

```
def iseven(x):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        return x," is even"
    else:
    return x," is odd"
it = (1)
while it >= 0:
    number = input("What number: ")
    print iseven(number)
    new_num = input("another number? answer (Y/N):")
    if new_num == "Y":
        it += 1
    else:
        it = 0
```

this is the error
    NameError: name 'Y' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Just change the line:

```
new_num = input("another number? answer (Y/N):")
```

to:

```
new_num = raw_input("another number? answer (Y/N):")
```

You need to change: `while it >= 0:` to `while it:` as well so that you can be able to exit the loop if you select `N` on prompt.

Comment: Because the OP uses python2 in his example and Y/N means a character Y or N must be specified to continue or to terminate the program. `raw_input` does not try to interpret the input data while `input` do.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to avoid `input` in such cases where you're processing general input and prefer `raw_input`:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

This avoid the `eval` that's taking place that's causing your error - it's looking in the program's scope for something named "Y". If you type "it", here, for example, it will evaluate the code, which is generally unsafe (though fairly benign here I suppose).

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval